# How to import / transfer system settings?

Tags: system-installation, settings

I installed elementary on a spare partition to test it. now I'm ready to replace my main linux installation with elementary, doing a clean new install.

how would I go about transferring my system settings to the new installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are in the hidden folder (name starts with a .) in your home folder (.cache, .config, .local, etc) to view these - while in files - press CTRL + H.

Just copy where the other OS installation is.